# List files with specific extension using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, sftp, winscp, directory-listing, winscp-net

I am using WinSCP .NET assembly to do a download and upload through SFTP with C# .NET. I have the download function working but I am looking for a way to have the files in the remote server listed (or at least listed with a specific extension) so user only have to choose from those files with the specific extension (like `.txt`) to get the files they want.

Is there a way to do that with WinSCP .NET assembly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Session.ListDirectories` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory):

```
RemoteDirectoryInfo directory = session.ListDirectory("/home/martin");

foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in directory.Files)
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileInfo.Name);
    if (string.Compare(extension, ".txt", true) == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} to listing", fileInfo.Name);
    }
}
```

---

Or the [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles):

```
IEnumerable<RemoteFileInfo> fileInfos =
    session.EnumerateRemoteFiles("/home/martin", "*.txt", EnumerationOptions.None);
foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} to listing", fileInfo.Name);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I think this is what I was looking for, will give it a try see if that works for me with some customization .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `RemoteFileInfo` and `RemoteDirectoryInfo` classes to get remote file and directory details. Then, depending on your requirements, you can use custom logic to retrieve specific files.

More info on that [here](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).