# Get the list of content of specific date on remote directory using WinSCP command line

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp, winscp

Currently I am using two commands.

First => This will list all files on particular path:

```
CommandText += @"/command ""option batch abort"" ""option confirm off"" ""Open """"" + SFTPAddress;
CommandText += @""""" -passive=on"" ""Put """"" + SourcePath;
CommandText += @""""" """"" + TargetPath + @"""""";
CommandText += @""" ""ls """"" + TargetPath + @"""""";
CommandText += @""" ""close"" ""exit"" ";
CommandText += @"/xmllog=""" + logname + @"""";
```

Second => This will list a file info of specific file:

```
CommandText += @"/command ""option batch abort"" ""option confirm off"" ""Open """"" + SFTPAddress;
CommandText += @""""" -passive=on"" ""Put """"" + SourcePath;
CommandText += @""""" """"" + TargetPath + @"""""";
CommandText += @""" ""stat """"" + TargetPath + filename + @"""""";
CommandText += @""" ""close"" ""exit"" ";
CommandText += @"/xmllog=""" + logname + @"""";
```

What I need is list all the files that were uploaded on a particular date with file info using command line.

Answer (score 1):

Since WinSCP 5.5.4 you can use [time-constraints](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time) with the [`ls`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_ls) command:

```
ls "*>2014-11-14"
```

References:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_ls
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time

---

Alternatively you can switch to the WinSCP .NET assembly:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

See the `Session.ListDirectory` method:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory

You can then easily filter returned collection using C# constructs.

See a similar question:
[List files with specific extension using WinSCP .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22667112/850848)

For details on converting your present script to WinSCP .NET assembly code see:
    https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_from_script